# Return Jersey exceptions in JSON

Tags: json, jersey

What is the best way to return Jersey exceptions in JSON format?
Here my sample code.

```
    public static class CompoThngExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Exception exception) {
        if (exception instanceof WebApplicationException) {
            WebApplicationException e = (WebApplicationException) exception;
            Response r = e.getResponse();
            return Response.status(r.getStatus()).entity(**HERE JSON**).build();
    } else {
            return null;

        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depends on what you want to return, but personally I have an `ErrorInfo` object that looks something like this:

```
public class ErrorInfo {
    final transient String developerMessage;
    final transient String userMessage;

    // Getters/setters/initializer
}
```

which I pass around as part of my `Exception`s, then I just use Jackson's `ObjectMapper` to create a JSON string from the  `ErrorInfo` object in the `ExceptionMapper`.  The nice thing with this approach is that you can extend it very easily, so adding status information, time of error, whatever, is just a case of adding another field.

Bear in mind that adding in things like the response's status is a bit of a waste, as that will be coming back in the HTTP header anyway.

**Update**

A complete example as follows (in this case ErrorInfo has more fields in it, but you get the general idea):

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@Provider
public class UnexpectedExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception>
{
  private static final transient ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper(); 

  @Override
  public Response toResponse(final Exception exception)
  {
    ResponseBuilder builder = Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                                      .entity(defaultJSON(exception))
                                      .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    return builder.build();
  }

  private String defaultJSON(final Exception exception)
  {
    ErrorInfo errorInfo = new ErrorInfo(null, exception.getMessage(), exception.getMessage(), (String)null);

    try
    {
      return MAPPER.writeValueAsString(errorInfo);
    }
    catch (JsonProcessingException e)
    {
      return "{\"message\":\"An internal error occurred\"}";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks jgm. Sorry. How do you encode the Jacson's `ObjectMapper` to create the JSON string from the `ErrorInfo` object in the `ExceptionMapper`???. Thanks in advance

Comment: Only last question jgm. I'm in Jetty - Jersey environment, and I always obtain a null in exception.getMessage(). I only want to return the status description. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That suggests that somewhere an exception is being thrown without a message.  Just change the creation of ErrorInfo to suit whatever you want to pass back.

Comment: The issue is that all the exceptions come with no exception message. I don't know if it's a thing of Jetty or Jersey or no idea

Comment: If it has no message it has no message.  Either put in a default one or make one up depending on the type of exception.

Answer (score 9):

Avoiding import Jackson classes but only stick to pure JAX-RS classes I create json exception wrappers like this.

Create ExceptionInfo wrapper and subclass various exception status types.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER)
@XmlRootElement
public class ExceptionInfo {
    private int status;
    private String msg, desc;
    public ExceptionInfo(int status, String msg, String desc) {
        this.status=status;
        this.msg=msg;
        this.desc=desc;
    }

    @XmlElement public int getStatus() { return status; }
    @XmlElement public String getMessage() { return msg; }
    @XmlElement public String getDescription() { return desc; }
}

- - - - 

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;

/**
 * Create 404 NOT FOUND exception
 */
public class NotFoundException extends WebApplicationException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public NotFoundException() {
        this("Resource not found", null);
    }

    /**
     * Create a HTTP 404 (Not Found) exception.
     * @param message the String that is the entity of the 404 response.
     */
    public NotFoundException(String msg, String desc) {
        super(Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).entity(
                new ExceptionInfo(Status.NOT_FOUND.getStatusCode(), msg, desc)
        ).type("application/json").build());
    }

}
```

Then throw exceptions in a resource implementation and client receives a nice json formatted http error body.

```
@Path("/properties")
public class PropertyService {
    ...
    @GET @Path("/{key}")
    @Produces({"application/json;charset=UTF-8"})
    public Property getProperty(@PathParam("key") String key) {
        // 200=OK(json obj), 404=NotFound
        Property bean = DBUtil.getProperty(key);
        if (bean==null) throw new NotFoundException();
        return bean;
    }   
    ...
}

- - - - 
Content-Type: application/json
{"status":404,"message":"Resource not found","description":null}
```

Comment: I don't get it. Where is this `ExceptionInfo` used? Or do you men that `NotFoundException` should extend `ExceptionInfo`?

Comment: @sja: See `NotFoundException(String msg, String desc)` constructor.